# Lantern failed to set as system proxy

Tags: networking, 20.04, proxy

I installed lantern with deb and

```
sudo dpkg -i lanter-installer-64-bit.deb
```

and now when I open lantern in http://localhost:42915, it says `connected` but in the top left corner on the little lantern icon it says:

`Status: failed to set lantern as system proxy`

I tried to manually change the proxy to `localhost:42915` but it didn't work.

I am on 20.04.5 LTS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNYC4.png)copy the HTTP(S) proxy to system netwrok proxy in setting and paste it to network proxy manual https proxy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Lantern **Settings - Advanced**
2. Open **Network Manager** (NM). Open Proxy tab.
3. Select Manual from dropdown and enter lanter settings:
   [image: Network Manager - Proxy settings]

- Lanter Https to NM Proxy Https
- Lanter SOCKS to NM Proxy Socks

**Check:**

4. Quit Lanter.
5. Open any URL in browser. If doesn't work - proxy is working properly.
6. Open Lanter
7. Check your external IP. E.g. here: https://www.myip.com/
   Voila! It works.

If not - reboot, close lanter and open again.